# laravel localhost and server work different with htaccess and public folder

Tags: laravel, server, localhost

After removing `.htaccess` from public to main, and renaming `server.php` to `index.php` all Asset links and links from the css background-image are wrong.

Is there a way to either have the same problem on localhost (the **/public** in the url) or is there an other easy fix? Cause right now if I fix my code on my online server, it doesn't work locally anymore and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

External CSS, Images and JS

Example Here,

Your URL Like:

**For CSS**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url('/public/file_name.css')}}">
```

**For JS**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('/public/file_name.js')}}">
```

After domain name, you must use **public** and then your CSS, images, and js path.